# Ставить большую букву после тире

Tags: javascript

Есть некоторая строка, которую нужно проверять на наличие в ней знака тире "-" и если этот знак есть тогда следующую букву после тире нужно сделать большой, ну а остальные далее идущие оставить как есть. Как это можно реализовать на JS ?

Например:

```
var str = "привет-стрАна"
```

Должно стать `"привет-СтрАна"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться [заменой](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) по регулярному выражению `/-\w/g`

**Важно:** данное выражение заменит только английские буквы.

```js
console.log("hello-worLd".replace(/-\w/g, $0 => $0.toUpperCase()));
console.log("hello-worLd-cebab".replace(/-\w/g, $0 => $0.toUpperCase()));
```

Для русских нужно добавить перечисление алфавита и не забыть букву `ё`, например так:

```js
console.log("привет-стрАна".replace(/-[а-яё]/g, $0 => $0.toUpperCase()));
console.log("привет-стрАна-кебаб".replace(/-[а-яё]/g, $0 => $0.toUpperCase()));
```

Чтобы и русский и английский

```js
console.log("привет-worLd-стрАна".replace(/-[a-zа-яё]/g, $0 => $0.toUpperCase()));
console.log("привет-worLd-стрАна-cebab-кебаб".replace(/-[a-zа-яё]/g, $0 => $0.toUpperCase()));
```

Comment: А можно так чтобы и с русскими ? Мне как раз для русских строк и надо. Спасибо

Comment: @PolyakovSergey, обновил ответ

Answer (score 7):

```js
var str = "-приВет-мИр-раЗ-два-ТРИ-heLlo-woRld-one-twO-THREE";

var i = -1;
while ((i = str.indexOf('-', i+1)) != -1) {
    str = str.substr(0, i+1) + str[i+1].toUpperCase() + str.substr(i+2);
}

console.log(str);
```

В условии цикла мы присваиваем переменной i положение символа '-' в строке, начиная поиск с (i+1)-ого символа, то есть каждый раз будет рассматриваться новое тире. Заметьте, что изначально мы присвоили переменной i значение -1, что бы в первый раз поиск шёл с нулевого символа.

В теле цикла происходит замена символов на позиции i+1 (то есть следующих после каждого тире) на соответствующие им заглавные с помощью .toUpperCase()

Так будет продолжаться, пока функция не вернёт -1, то есть пока мы не рассмотрим все тире.

Comment: стоит добавить описание что происходит в блоке кода

Comment: @Grundy, там просто замена символа на позиции i+1 (то есть следующего после тире) на соответствующий ему большой (с помощью .toUpperCase())

Comment: Вот это описание и добавь в ответ

Comment: Добавил, спасибо)

Comment: @PolyakovSergey, это решение в отличии от регулярок из другого ответа даже с глаголицей работает :)

Comment: @Visman, с регулярками хотя бы выглядит читаемо.

Comment: @СемушинСергей, не работает для случая `-приВет-мИр-раЗ`, то есть когда строка _начинается_ с `-`

Comment: @Grundy исправил, и снова спасибо)

Comment: @СемушинСергей, объяснения лучше из кода вынести, чтобы не было дублирования абсолютно одинакового кода

Comment: @Grundy, готово